# ОС для запуска java-приложений в виртуальных машинах

Tags: ос, виртуализация

Добрый день, посоветуйте, пожалуйста, операционную систему для того, чтобы запустить приложение, написанное на java в нескольких виртуальных машинах, чтобы изолировать их друг от друга. 
Имеется в виду ос с минимальным требованием к ОЗУ, чтобы запустить параллельно по 10-20 виртмашин.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужна полная изоляция и VM, то я бы посмотрел в сторону [Alpine Linux](https://alpinelinux.org/). 
А так, Docker.